# how to create cell with many data in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Im new in iphone and I want know that what can create tableview with many cell of object like this :

```
NSMutableArray *animal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lion",@"Tiger",@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Sheep",@"Wolf", nil];
```

in tableview that when to click any cell fo on next page that is tableview with many object of first object (like this : lion 1,lion 2,lion 3,lion 4,lion 5,...)

so I want that create tableview in tableview another ...

please guide me. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use following table View's method

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return animal.count;
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

     cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIdex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Below method is use for fire Action When you select row from UITableView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
         // Create Object of you SecondViewController for go on.
     SecondViewController *tlController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
     tlController.animalName = [array objectAtIndex:insexpath.row];// here you need to pass name of animal on SecondViewController, and in SecondViewController you need to display animal name related to pass from previous view controller.

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:tlController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: thank you what I do for next page??? next page is this table view

Comment: @janatan-check it by last method from my code :)

Comment: @janatan-sory ignore it ..it is not useful for u :)

Comment: if I have another NSArray in my code like this (    color = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Red",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Black", nil];
) and I want show in table view what I do?

Comment: I want show animal array and color array in table view

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you need to set your tableview's datasource and delegate through your xib.

Now to return numberofrows in your tableview , there is one delegate method

> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { }

here you can return animal.count;
This will create 10 cells, if you have 10 objects in your array.

```
> 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  UITableViewCell
    *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
         if (cell == nil) {
              cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [animal objectatIndex:indexpath.ro];
        return cell;
}
```

This will return tableview with objects existing in your animal array. 
And after that to get selected row's detail , there is one method , didselectrowatindexpath . Try googling it.
That's it .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please do better research before posting any questions here .May help you [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)